# Unique alphanumeric key generator

Tags: objective-c, ipad, alphanumeric

Am developing an app in iPad. Using the app i am going to record videos and upload it into the server. I would like to generate a unique alphanumeric key to be used as the video name. IS there any way to generate alphanumeric key in objective-c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following function to get random name it will give you very long name so specify the name length you required in my case it is 8.

```
-(NSString*)getRandomAlphanumericString 
{
    CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil);//create a new UUID
    NSString *uuidString = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj);
    CFRelease(uuidObj);
    return [uuidString substringToIndex:8]; //specify length here. even you can use full 
}
```